# Conditional formatting not working when copied from Excel to Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have copied the formula: =OR($B$7:$AS$7="N") from conditional formatting in excel to a google sheet and it is not working correctly. It works perfectly in Excel.

I have already tried removing the $ symbols to no avail and I am sure there is some issue with the OR function and the colon from some investigation but can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Image showing the problem.]

Comment: It isn't working. However if I change it to: =OR(B7="N",AS7="N") it works as is expected. Unsure why putting a : in the middle seems to mess everything up.

Comment: I don't want it to apply to each individual cell in that row but to a separate cell entirely. See my picture above.

Comment: Created a workaround using: =COUNTIF(B7:AS7,"N")>=1

Comment: Try entering the formula as an array formula if you want to use the original fomula =ArrayFormula(OR($B$7:$AS$7="N"))

Answer (score 0):

Created a workaround using:

```
=COUNTIF(B7:AS7,"N")>=1
```